# Vocativo ou aposto?

Tags: gramática, vocativos

Hoje, eu estava lendo [esta notícia](http://jbfilhoreporter.final.com.br/2017/04/06/inter-pode-ser-denunciado-em-artigo-da-fifa-e-ai-a-coisa-fica-muito-feia/) a respeito da possibilidade de uma punição do clube de futebol Sport Club Internacional que o levaria a ser excluído da Série B do Campeonato Brasileiro e, consequentemente, à disputa da Série C no próximo ano. Segue um trecho:

> O reconhecido repórter carioca, Wellington Campos, que cobre o dia a dia da 
>       CBF, noticiou que o Internacional poderá ser denunciado no artigo 61 da FIFA 
>       por conta do processo de falsificação do e-mail.[...]

Um comentário abaixo do texto pedia “uma vírgula antes de Wellington, na primeira linha, por tratar-se de vocativo”. Não seria a necessidade de se ter a vírgula antes de “Wellington Campos” apenas porque o nome é um **aposto**, visto que está detalhando de quem se fala quando se diz “reconhecido repórter carioca”?

Answer (score 3):

Não é difícil.

> O famoso repórter, Wellington Campos, está vindo aí. (aposto)
>
> Êi, Wellington Campos, venha aqui. (vocativo)

Vocativo serve para chamar alguém. Aposto serve para explicar algo (tipo, o repórter famoso de quem estou falando é o Wellington Campos, não o Tintin ou o Clark Kent).

Assim,

> Ó leitor do texto (*vocativo*), o famoso repórter, Zé das Couves (aposto), quer falar com você.

Se o receptor da mensagem é o leitor do texto, então o vocativo será "leitor do texto" ou equivalente. Se o receptor da mensagem for Wellington Campos (isto é, se estivermos falando com o Wellington Campos), então o vocativo será "Wellington Campos" ou equivalente.

O vocativo sempre aceita um "ó" antes, o aposto nunca.

Comment: Mas normalmente não separamos com vírgula ou outra pontuação o ***ó*** do resto do vocativo.

Comment: @Jacinto De fato, não, provavelmente por que o ***ó*** faz parte do vocativo.

Comment: Já tinha ficado a pensar se o ***ó*** fazia ou não parte do vocativo. Mas para mim a ausência de vírgula reflete a entoação: em "ó João, vem aqui", nós pronunciamos "ó João"  tudo de seguida; ao contrário de "ei, João..." ou mesmo "ei! João..."

Answer (score -1):

Seguindo a definição de Vocativo e Aposto conforme abaixo retirado de [Mundo Educação](http://mundoeducacao.bol.uol.com.br/gramatica/aposto-vocativo.htm), Acredito que seria um Aposto, se tivesse escrita ao contrário, no caso, explicando quem é Wellington

Wellington Campos, reconhecido reporter carioca, que cobre o dia a dia da CBF[...]

Nesse caso, o nome do reporter está deslocado da frase, podendo ser considerado um vocativo.

> Aposto e Vocativo Aposto e vocativo são termos que compõem uma oração,
>   o aposto explica, esclarece e acrescenta algo ao sujeito; o vocativo
>   serve para invocar o receptor da mensagem.
>
> Publicado por: Marina Cabral em Termos constituintes da oração
>
> ```
>  Aposto é o termo que, acrescentado a outro termo da oração, explica ou esclarece o sentido de um nome; aparece geralmente separado
> ```
>
> por vírgulas ou depois de dois pontos.
>
> O aposto pode ser:
>
> - explicativo: Alexandre, presidente do clube, fez a premiação.
> - enumerativo: Tocaram duas músicas: um samba e um forró.
> - recapitulativo (resumidor): Os atabaques, os tamborins, as cuícas, tudo ficou lá.
> - comparativo: “A inflação, monstro devorador dos salários, é sempre uma ameaça...”
> - especificativo (esse tipo não se separa por pontuação do nome a que se refere): A escritora Lygia Fagundes Telles lançou mais um conto.
>
> Vocativo é um termo descolado sintaticamente da oração, não pertence
>   nem ao sujeito, nem ao predicado. Ele serve para invocar o receptor da
>   mensagem.

Comment: Não seria o receptor da mensagem, nesse caso, o leitor do texto? Nesse caso, eu e não o repórter.

Comment: @MagisterMundus "Wellington Campos" é aposto, não é vocativo.

Comment: @Jacinto, poderia elaborar uma resposta?

Comment: @MagisterMundus Agora quero esparramar-me no sofá e descansar. Mas se não aparecer uma resposta satisfatória, ou esta que melhore ou outra que apareça, eu escrevo uma.